# Can you give me an example that causes memory fragmentation in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, memory

I'm working to make our application more performant by caching more stuff in memory. What worries me, though, is all that I'm reading about how the large object heap is not really compacted during a garbage collection, and that this can cause memory fragmentation.

I've been doing some small testing, but it seems I can't induce this problem. So here's my question: Can you show me a code snippet in C# that would, at some point, cause failure due to memory fragmentation?

Comment: Sounds more like an exploit, doesn't it?

Comment: No, I'm specifically looking for a pattern that fails if it doesn't take this 'memory fragmentation' into account.

Comment: A loop that copies files to random locations and terminates in the middle of the copying will fragmess up your hard disk...

Comment: Take a look at this code by cfneese posted on 11/04/2011 at 22:54 in this article http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/521147/large-object-heap-fragmentation-causes-outofmemoryexception

Comment: @ChibuezeOpata i'm talking about memory fragmentation.

Comment: @chridam Great! Why not post it as an answer? That aside, running the example does not produce the problem in .NET 4.0.

Comment: @DaveVandenEynde Absolutely, at least it's given you a nudge in the right direction.

Comment: Hmmm, you can still apply the same concept to memory allocation. difference is, the .net runtime is in charge in that case...

Comment: @ChibuezeOpata I think it's a bit more complicated than that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try having a look at the code snippet in this article [The Dangers of the Large Object Heap](http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/the-dangers-of-the-large-object-heap/) and implementing this code just after the catch block of the Fill function to fragment the LOH, as outlined by cfneese posted on 11/04/2011 in the comments for the bug [Large Object Heap fragmentation causes OutOfmemoryException](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/521147/large-object-heap-fragmentation-causes-outofmemoryexception) :

```
        unsafe
        {
            var w = new StreamWriter(@".\test.txt");
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                var handle = GCHandle.Alloc(smallBlocks[i], GCHandleType.Pinned);
                w.WriteLine(String.Format("{0,10}\t{1,10}", i, handle.AddrOfPinnedObject()));
                handle.Free();
            }
            w.Close();
        }
```